# On By Default Check of Radio Button, I want to show the form defaultely

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, validation, radio-button

I have a registration page Containing Three forms.I want to register the User and Service provider both from same page.

1 - Consist Two Radio Buttons [Service Provider and User].
 2 - form for the registration of service provider on Radio Button 1.
 3 - form for the registration of user on Radio Button 2.

I have achieved the functionality through radio button onChange event to open respective form in the div tag of that page. Used style display:none for that and showed it when radio button change.

I am on CodeIgniter Framework of PHP. I want to do validation of both forms.
So for that reason...

Now scenario is that,

I have checked the first radio button. But I want to do that, On by default check of that, I want to open first form of service provider defaultely with event only. Other then that, I can do that with removal of style display:none. But I don't want to do that with it. I want to do on event based.

My Form of Radio Buttons.

```
<form>
<input value="1" type="radio" name="formselector" onchange="displayForm(this)" checked="checked"></input>Service Provider
                                    <br><input value="2" type="radio" name="formselector" onchange="displayForm(this)"></input>User

                                </form>
```

JS for above radio buttons.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function displayForm(c) {
            if (c.value == "1") {

                document.getElementById("ccform").style.display = 'inline';
                document.getElementById("paypalform").style.display = 'none';
            } else if (c.value == "2") {
                document.getElementById("ccform").style.display = 'none';

                document.getElementById("paypalform").style.display = 'inline';
            } else {
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Now Two forms Div tag.

```
    <div id="form">
                           <!-- <form role="form" id="form" class="login-form" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Home/add_service_provider" method="post" onsubmit="return fun();">                             
                            --><form style="display:none" id="ccform">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-icon"> 
                                                                        <!--<i class="styled-select service-select"></i>-->

                                        <i class="fa fa-building"></i>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="city" style="padding-left:38px" >
                                            <option value="">Choose City</option>
                                            <?php
                                            $i = 0;
                                            foreach ($city as $row) {
                                                ?>
                                                <option class="subitem"  name="city" value="<?php echo $row->city_name ?>"><?php echo $row->city_name ?></option>
                                            <?php } ?>     
                                        </select>  

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-icon">
                                        <i class="fa fa-tint"></i>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="area" style="padding-left:38px" >
                                            <option value="">Choose Area</option>
                                            <?php
                                            $i = 0;
                                            foreach ($areaname as $row) {
                                                ?>
                                                <option class="subitem" name="area" value="<?php echo $row->area_name ?>"><?php echo $row->area_name ?></option>
                                            <?php } ?>     
                                        </select>   
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-icon">
                                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="service" style="padding-left:38px" >
                                            <option value="">Choose Service</option>
                                            <?php
                                            $i = 0;
                                            foreach ($service as $row) {
                                                ?>
                                                <option class="subitem" name="service" value="<?php echo $row->category_name ?>"><?php echo $row->category_name ?></option>
                                            <?php } ?>     
                                        </select>   
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-icon">
                                        <i class="icon fa fa-user"></i>
                                        <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" name="username[]" placeholder="First Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-icon">
                                        <i class="icon fa fa-user"></i>
                                        <input type="text" id="lastname" class="form-control" name="username[]" placeholder="Last Name" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>                              
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-icon">
                                        <i class="icon fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                        <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-icon">
                                        <i class="icon fa fa-unlock-alt"></i>
                                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-icon">
                                        <i class="icon fa fa-unlock-alt"></i>
                                        <input type="password" id="cpassword" name="cpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Retype Password" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox form-group">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="remember" value="forever" style="float: left;">
                                    <label for="remember">By creating account you agree to our Terms & Conditions</label>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-common log-btn" id="submit">Register</button>
                            </form>
<!-- <form role="form" class="login-form" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Home/add_user" onsubmit="return fun();"> -->
                            <form style="display:none" id="paypalform">    
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-icon">
                                        <i class="icon fa fa-user"></i>
                                        <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" name="username[]" placeholder="First Name" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-icon">
                                        <i class="icon fa fa-user"></i>
                                        <input type="text" id="lastname" class="form-control" name="username[]" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-icon">
                                        <i class="icon fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                        <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-icon">
                                        <i class="icon fa fa-unlock-alt"></i>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-icon">
                                        <i class="icon fa fa-unlock-alt"></i>
                                        <input type="password" name="cPassword" id="cPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Retype Password" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                 
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="rememberme" value="forever" style="float: left;" required>
                                    <label for="remember">By creating account you agree to our Terms & Conditions</label>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-common log-btn" id="register">Register</button>
                            </form>


                        </div>
```

Most important thing is.. I want to do validation with CodeIgniter Standard.
My problem is that,

Assume a scenario... Currently I am filling the form of User registration. Now on submit button click. It will go for validation check. Assume validation gets failed. It will redirect to this signup page but, User form will not be displayed with the error of validation because radio button not gets selected.

Hope You understand my problem.

Please bear with the css and all these things.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Radio button Code :

```
 <form>
        <input value="1" type="radio" id="chk1" name="formselector" onchange="displayForm(this)" checked="checked"></input>Service Provider
        <br><input value="2" id="chk2" type="radio" name="formselector" onchange="displayForm(this)"></input>User

</form>
```

Html Form

```
<div id="form">
    <form style="display:none" id="ccform">
        <div class="form-group">
           <div class="input-icon"> 
               <i class="fa fa-building"></i>
                <select class="form-control" name="city" style="padding-left:38px" >
                 <option value="">Choose City</option>
                 <?php
                 $i = 0;
                 foreach ($city as $row) {
                 ?>
                 <option class="subitem"  name="city" value="<?php echo $row->city_name ?>"><?php echo $row->city_name ?></option>
                 <?php } ?>     
                 </select>  
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-tint"></i>
                            <select class="form-control" name="area" style="padding-left:38px" >
                                <option value="">Choose Area</option>
                                <?php
                                $i = 0;
                                foreach ($areaname as $row) {
                                ?>
                                <option class="subitem" name="area" value="<?php echo $row->area_name ?>"><?php echo $row->area_name ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>     
                            </select>   
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                            <select class="form-control" name="service" style="padding-left:38px" >
                                <option value="">Choose Service</option>
                                <?php
                                $i = 0;
                                foreach ($service as $row) {
                                ?>
                                <option class="subitem" name="service" value="<?php echo $row->category_name ?>"><?php echo $row->category_name ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>     
                            </select>   
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-icon">
                            <i class="icon fa fa-user"></i>
                            <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" name="username[]" placeholder="First Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-icon">
                            <i class="icon fa fa-user"></i>
                            <input type="text" id="lastname" class="form-control" name="username[]" placeholder="Last Name" >
                        </div>
                    </div>                              
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-icon">
                            <i class="icon fa fa-envelope"></i>
                            <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-icon">
                            <i class="icon fa fa-unlock-alt"></i>
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" >
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-icon">
                            <i class="icon fa fa-unlock-alt"></i>
                            <input type="password" id="cpassword" name="cpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Retype Password" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox form-group">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="remember" value="forever" style="float: left;">
                        <label for="remember">By creating account you agree to our Terms & Conditions</label>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-common log-btn" id="submit">Register</button>
                </form>
                <form style="display:none" id="paypalform">    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-icon">
                            <i class="icon fa fa-user"></i>
                            <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" name="username[]" placeholder="First Name" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-icon">
                            <i class="icon fa fa-user"></i>
                            <input type="text" id="lastname" class="form-control" name="username[]" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-icon">
                            <i class="icon fa fa-envelope"></i>
                            <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-icon">
                            <i class="icon fa fa-unlock-alt"></i>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-icon">
                            <i class="icon fa fa-unlock-alt"></i>
                            <input type="password" name="cPassword" id="cPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Retype Password" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>                 
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="rememberme" value="forever" style="float: left;" required>
                        <label for="remember">By creating account you agree to our Terms & Conditions</label>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-common log-btn" id="register">Register</button>
                </form>
 </div>
```

Javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                var i= document.getElementById('chk1').checked;
                var j= document.getElementById('chk2').checked;
                if(i==true){
                    document.getElementById("ccform").style.display = 'inline';
                }
                if(j==true){
                    document.getElementById("paypalform").style.display = 'inline';
                }
                function displayForm(c) {
                    if (c.value == "1") {

                        document.getElementById("ccform").style.display = 'inline';
                        document.getElementById("paypalform").style.display = 'none';
                    } else if (c.value == "2") {
                        document.getElementById("ccform").style.display = 'none';

                        document.getElementById("paypalform").style.display = 'inline';
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            </script>
```

Here you can check example

https://codepen.io/sunny_khatri/pen/VpoXoQ

Answer (score 0):

you will found more details about validation here https://www.formget.com/form-validation-using-codeigniter/